# Simple forloop - Python

Tags: python

this is probably too simple of a question, but here I go.

I have paginated items, each page contains 100 items. The program fetches items till it reaches the item index specified within item_num

This is what I have:

```
item_num = 56

range(0, item_num/100 + (item_num%100 > 0)):
  get_next_100()
```

---

I'm not really sure about the **(item_num%100 > 0) boolean** I used.

Is there anything wrong with what I did?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

range takes a 3rd optional parameter of step.

So

```
range(0,234,100)
```

Gives

```
[0, 100, 200]
```

So you can do something like

```
for items in range(0,234,100):
    get_next_100()
```

Comment: @cb160: actually... this is indeed the perfect answer!

Comment: as I commented on Mark Byers answer, you might also consider `xrange` if you are using python version < 3.0

Answer (score 6):

You seem to be trying to call the function zero times if item_num is 0, once if item_num is 1 to 100, twice if item_num is between 101 and 200, etc...

A simpler way to write this is:

```
n = 0
while n < item_num:
   get_next_100()
   n += 100
```

Or you could do it as a for loop:

```
for _ in range(0, item_num, 100):
   get_next_100()
```

Comment: you might also consider `xrange` if you are using python version < 3.0

Comment: @Mark: hey Mark. Thanks for your answer! I'm using 1-based numbering btw.

Comment: @Radiant: Ah yep, it seemed that you were trying to do something more complicated.